# Is it possible to disable the close button unless the window is focused? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, user-interface

From time to time, I close the wrong windows by mistake. That is because I want to close the focused (i.e. topmost) window but mistook the close button of another window as the close button of the focused window. Another common case is the focused window looks maximized but actually not. So when I want to close it, I click on the top-right corner of the screen. But because the window is not maximized, I actually click on the close button of another window. So, does it make more sense that when clicking on the close button of an unfocused window, that window should just be focused instead of closed? How can I set Windows 10 in this way?
[An example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucaKM.png)

Comment: I do it often, its very frustrating.  Especially since new programs are not displaying the caption and windows does not like making the caption for an active window stand out.  I keep applying tweaks for it, and the windows updates keep removing it.

Comment: @RohitGupta Would you like to explain what tweaks are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alleviate some of the issues by using **Windows Tweaks** or **Registry Hacks**.  There are many of them out there.

[Winaero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/winaero-tweaker/) in this case is your best option.

1. After installing, run it
2. Find **Appearance** in the tree on the left hand side
3. Click on **Colored Title Bars**
4. On the right hand pane, click on **Enable Colored Title Bars**
5. It will recreate any existing windows

And thats it.  Focused Windows will have a blue title bar.  Note that some applications hide the title bar, so they will not change in appearance.

The exception is **Firefox**.  To enable the title bar

1. Right Click on an empty space at the top around the tabs area
2. Tick **Menu Bar**